# Save data from a Django FileUploadHandler into a model

Tags: python, django, file-upload

I create a subclass of Django's FileUploadHandler which counts lines in uploaded files.
I want to save this count in a model field.

**What are my options?**

I know I have access to the `request` in the FileUploadHandler - should I just stick the line count into the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to stick the aggregate info into the returned file-like object:

```
class TemporaryFileUploadHandler(DjangoTemporaryFileUploadHandler):
    def new_file(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TemporaryFileUploadHandler, self).new_file(*args, **kwargs)
        self.line_count = 1

    def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
        self.file.write(raw_data)
        self.line_count += raw_data.count(b'\n')

    def file_complete(self, file_size):
        fobj = super(TemporaryFileUploadHandler, self).file_complete(file_size)
        setattr(fobj, 'line_count', self.line_count)
        return fobj
```